# Fitting a grid to a research plot

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, pix4d

I am trying to create a grid to use for zonal stats for a ag research plot. I have created some grids and rotated them and am getting decent fittings but I feel that there must be some other better way to fit the grid to the plot. Is there some way to define the boundaries of the plot with points and to fit the grid to those points or something along those lines (no pun intended)? What is the best way to create a grid for this type of analysis? Also and more importantly, I am thinking that I would like some empty space in-between the boundaries pf each grid cell, how would I create a such a grid?

I am working in qgis with imagery processed in pix4d. The plots are generally rectangular.

Comment: Have a look at these similar questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/258912/81764 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/210461/81764